# Angular - Type 'SortState | undefined' is not assignable to type 'SortState'

Tags: angular

In Angular-13 paged-query.ts I have this code:

```
import {HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';

export class PagedQuery {
  private sortList = new Map<string, SortState>();
  private filterList = new Array<SortRecord>();

  pageIndex: number = 1;
  pageSize: number = 10;

  public clearSorts() {
    this.sortList.clear();
  }

  public getSortStateFor(propertyPath: string) : SortState {
    return this.sortList.has(propertyPath)
      ? this.sortList.get(propertyPath)
      : SortState.Off;
  }    
}

export enum SortState {
  Off = "-",
  Asc = "asc",
  Desc = "desc"
}
```

I got this error:

> Type 'SortState | undefined' is not assignable to type 'SortState'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SortState'.ts(232

and this line is highlighted"

```
return this.sortList.has(propertyPath)
  ? this.sortList.get(propertyPath)
  : SortState.Off;
```

in  getSortStateFor()

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  public getSortStateFor(propertyPath: string) : SortState {
    return this.sortList.get(propertyPath) ?? SortState.Off;
  }
```